# upgrading bitcoind (-qt) from 0.9.3 to 0.10

Tags: ubuntu

I have version 0.9.3 of bitcoind (-qt) on my Ubuntu server and I want to
upgrade to 0.10.0, I just want to keep the blockchain and I have nothing in my wallet.

from https://bitcoin.org/en/release/v0.10.0, I found
"or just copy over bitcoind/bitcoin-qt (on Linux)"

If I do

```
sudo find / -name '*bitcoin-qt*'
/usr/local/src/bitcoin-0.9.3/src/qt/res/bitcoin-qt-res.rc
/usr/local/src/bitcoin-0.9.3/contrib/bitcoin-qt.pro
/usr/local/src/bitcoin-0.9.3/contrib/debian/manpages/bitcoin-qt.1
/usr/local/src/bitcoin-0.9.3/contrib/debian/bitcoin-qt.lintian-overrides
/usr/local/src/bitcoin-0.9.3/contrib/debian/bitcoin-qt.protocol
/usr/local/src/bitcoin-0.9.3/contrib/debian/bitcoin-qt.install
/usr/local/src/bitcoin-0.9.3/contrib/debian/bitcoin-qt.desktop
/usr/local/bin/bitcoin-qt
/usr/local/bin/test_bitcoin-qt
```

I find few files in .../bitcoin-0.9.3/...I guess those files have been used to compile the binary file /usr/local/bin/bitcoin-qt.

Then I can replace the binary bitcoin-qt with the new one in /usr/local/bin/ and remove everything in bitcoin-0.9.3? Is it correct ? Same question for bitcoind:

```
sudo find / -name '*bitcoind*'
/usr/local/src/bitcoin-0.9.3/src/bitcoind.o
/usr/local/src/bitcoin-0.9.3/src/bitcoind.cpp
/usr/local/src/bitcoin-0.9.3/src/.deps/bitcoind.Po
/usr/local/src/bitcoin-0.9.3/src/bitcoind-res.rc
/usr/local/src/bitcoin-0.9.3/src/bitcoind
/usr/local/src/bitcoin-0.9.3/contrib/bitcoind.bash-completion
/usr/local/src/bitcoin-0.9.3/contrib/debian/manpages/bitcoind.1
/usr/local/src/bitcoin-0.9.3/contrib/debian/bitcoind.manpages
/usr/local/src/bitcoin-0.9.3/contrib/debian/bitcoind.examples
/usr/local/src/bitcoin-0.9.3/contrib/debian/bitcoind.install
/usr/local/src/bitcoin-0.9.3/contrib/debian/bitcoind.bash-completion
/usr/local/src/bitcoin-0.9.3/contrib/debian/bitcoind.lintian-overrides
/usr/local/src/bitcoin-0.9.3/qa/pull-tester/run-bitcoind-for-test.sh.in
/usr/local/src/bitcoin-0.9.3/qa/pull-tester/run-bitcoind-for-test.sh
/usr/local/bin/bitcoind
```

And last question: what do I do with all those files in the .tar.gz archive downloaded from the web:

```
bitcoin-0.10.0/bin/bitcoin-cli
bitcoin-0.10.0/bin/bitcoind
bitcoin-0.10.0/bin/bitcoin-qt
bitcoin-0.10.0/bin/bitcoin-tx
bitcoin-0.10.0/bin/test_bitcoin
bitcoin-0.10.0/bin/test_bitcoin-qt

bitcoin-0.10.0/include/bitcoinconsensus.h

bitcoin-0.10.0/lib/libbitcoinconsensus.so -> libbitcoinconsensus.so.0.0.0
bitcoin-0.10.0/lib/libbitcoinconsensus.so.0 -> libbitcoinconsensus.so.0.0.0
bitcoin-0.10.0/lib/libbitcoinconsensus.so.0.0.0
```

Comment: I don't believe you can keep the Blockchain. You can back it up but v0.9.x is not back compatible with v0.1.0 *headers first* Blockchain FWIW

Comment: @WizardOfOzzie It's not backwards compatible, but it is forwards compatible.